# help with htaccess query strings appending constantly

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, paging

I have an htaccess rule that goes:

```
RewriteRule ^Commercial-Units/For-Sale/(([a-zA-Z]+)*/([0-9]+)*/([a-zA-Z]+)*/([0-9]+)*/([a-zA-Z]+)*/([0-9]+)*)*$ pages/index.php?f=quicksearch&cust_wants=1&want_type=2&at=$3&start=$5&limit=$7 [R=302,L]
```

This is specifically designed for when a page requires paging records.

I have been trying to find solutions over everywhere in Google and Stackoverflow.com..

The problem is that everytime someone clicks on, say page 2, the address bar keeps on adding my query strings like so:

```
http://mysite.com/Commerial-Units/For-Sale/page/2/at/10/limit/7/page/2/at/10/limit/7
```

notice that the url above containes multiple key-value combinations duplicated and this goes on and on everytime someone clicks on the next page...

Hope someone can point me to the right solution to this...

Thank you very much!

Comment: This sounds like something that is caused by your page, not .htaccess - for example, relative links in your document. What do your links look like?

Comment: aha! you are a super genius, this has solved the problem. All my links are using absolute paths and they work ok, but all my pagers are just configured to use relative paths! Changing them to absolute solved it! However, I was just using absolute paths because enabling htaccess in my site will break my links and pages..

Comment: if there is no http:// in your link it is not an absolute link

Answer (score 0):

Thats not a problem with your rewrite but with your site code the links are adding `/page/2/at/10/limit/7` to the current url you need to remove the previous params using something like `../../../../../../page/2/at/10/limit/7`

And if that is for SEO please use parameters for pagination, only use SEO friendly urls for categories and items, no need to index every single pagination option, as that will be duplicated content.

Comment: I was going to trim the paging url to something like: http://mysite.com/Commercial-Units/For-Sale/page/2 and remove the other params that is required for my paging class. Unfortunately i need to keep track in the GET string my startat position and limit for the mysql query to pick up. Can you suggest anyway I could do this?

Comment: First you can hard code the size of the pages so if the items per page is always 10 page 2 will be 10-20, 3 20-30 ans so on. If you allow changing the number of items per page (and it is not a global user setting) then use params for that mysite.com/Commercial-Units/For-Sale?from=X&to=Y only need 2 params and google will not index subsequent pages only the one without params